# Merging polygons using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I need to do a simple merge polygon in PostGIS. The attribute table from both input shapefiles needs to be preserved. This is easily done In QGIS by using the merge polygon tool. But I don’t know how to do this in PostGIS.

I want to merge poly1 and poly2 – see picture (done in QGIS).

[image]

I have tried with the code below, but this gives way to many rows (should be around 5000, but it gives more 1 millions rows:

```
CREATE TABLE land_merge as
SELECT ST_Union(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) as geom
FROM poly1, poly2;
```

Comment: Look at what your SQL really requests: "Generate one row in land_merge for every row in poly for every row in poly2." So yeah, starting with thousands, the Cartesian product *should* be millions. Do you just want to append the two tables, or do you want to merge, dissolving on some common key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables doesnt look like they overlap so I think you want to use the  [postgres union operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/queries-union.html) to combine the two selections:

```
CREATE TABLE Results as
SELECT * from poly1
UNION
SELECT * from poly2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactely what i needed

Comment: do you know how I can merge with different number of columns? I got this error when i tried to merge two polygons with different # of columns: ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 4: SELECT * poly2

Comment: I havent tried that. But a quick google says it seems to be possible, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122151/postgresql-append-two-tables-with-different-columns/50122404